# How do we calculate the $\operatorname{Ext}^{2}(k(p),\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $p$ be a closed point on $\mathbb{P}_{k}^{2}$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Let $I_{p}$ be the ideal sheaf at $p$, then we will have an exact sequence

$$0\to I_{p}\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}\to k(p)\to 0$$

Where $k(p)$ is the corresponding skyscraper sheaf.

Now I want to calculate $\operatorname{Ext}^{2}(k(p), \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2})$.Since $H^{1}(\mathbb{P}^2, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2})=H^2({\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}})=0$, $\operatorname{Ext}^{2}(k(p), \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2})\cong \operatorname{Ext}^{1}(I_{p},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2})$. But also, I do not know what should I do next. Could you help? Thanks

Comment: One option is to use the Koszul resolution $$0 \to \mathcal{O}(-2) \to \mathcal{O}(-1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1) \to I_p \to 0.$$

Comment: $I_p$ has a nice resolution $0\to O(-2)\to O(-1)\oplus O(-1)\to I_p\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know how to calculate now.